# word meaning before or after?

Tags: word-choice

This is my first time on the English portion of Stack Exchange

I'm creating a function that gets events from a table. One of the parameters of the function is whether the event is in the future or in the past.

`function getEvents($param)`

I'm looking for a word that means in the past OR in the future.

My mind is blanking out on having one and have had little luck finding one online.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are capable of polite and complete sentences when asking a question, you should ask your question such a way, rather than having someone clean it up for you.

Comment: Are you looking for a name for the function or for the parameter?

Comment: I'd go for OccuranceType

Comment: How about **NotNow**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming a variable

Comment: Naming functions and variables is expressly off-topic here, and in fact the answers and comments so far quite aptly demonstrate why. Mind you, this *can* be turned into a language question; but right now the exact opposite is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You might be blanking because there is no common way to express that, I don't think.  Since you are dealing with code, you might like:

- $notatthistime
- $not_now
- $some_other_time

You're going to have to use your imagination.

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented env, your function declaration would be

```
enum TimePerspective{
  PAST, PRESENT, FUTURE;
}

void getEvents(TimePerspective perspective);
```

In place of the word TimePerspective, the following might make more sense

- TimePhase
- TimeMode
- HistoryMode
- Tense

Why not simply use `Tense`?

```
enum Tense{
  PAST, PRESENT, FUTURE;
}

void getEvents(Tense tense);
```

In Javascript,

```
function getEvents(tense)
```

Answer (score 0):

**non-present**

I remember seeing something of the kind in a grammatical description

*non-present  = {past, future}*

and by analogy

*non-past = {present, future} 

non-future = {past, present}*